# Are the Grpc stub files platform agostic

Tags: grpc

Grpc tools has 2 folders - windows_x64, windows_x86. The exe's (grpc_csharp_plugin, protoc) are of different size but the stub files created by them are the same.

Can I conclude that the folders for x64, x86 denote the platform on which the exe's are run and NOT the targeted platform's for the stub files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the codegen does not vary by platform. There is only a different stub generation per language. To help users run the code generator (which is C++) there are pre-built binaries for a variety of common platforms. All platforms generate the same code.